# Is it normal/acceptable for plugin/theme developers to ask for an admin login to investigate a trouble ticket?

Tags: plugins, support

I shan't name and shame, but basically, we had a plugin on our site that would cause the page its content was embedded into to disappear if the site's PHP version was higher than PHP5, which was sad as what it provided was really helpful. As having a lower PHP version was slowing down our site pretty significantly, we ended up updating the PHP and going with an alternative to the apparently tetchy plugin. When I went to deactivate the original plugin, I was given the option to give a reason why, so I gave a brief comment on the issue;

> The page that the ******** is embedded into will disappear if the site's PHP is newer than PHP5.

Later that afternoon, I got an e-mail from one of the members of the plugin's dev team;

> Dear *****,
>
> Thank you for contacting ********** Support Team!
>
> We are terribly sorry for the inconvenience. Could you please give us temporary WordPress admin access to your website? Our development team will take a look at the problem and figure out a solution as soon as possible.
>
> Please note, that any sensitive information you provide is secured by our strong Privacy Statement. Feel free to look at it, if you'd like:
>   https://*****/****
>
> Thanks! Have a great day!

'Strong privacy statement' or not, I find it quite odd and even slightly suspect that they would want admin access to our site, and I wouldn't be comfortable doing so anyhow as our site contains a lot of our customers' private information. Am I wrong in being suspicious?

Answer (score 1):

If I really needed such plugin to function I would clone the site, remove all private information and provide admin access to the clone. It will take you some time to do so, but if you need it, I think this is the best you can do.